# JOLT JSON transform values from one-to-many to one-to-one

Tags: json, jolt

I'm trying to map one key to each value in array to a new array by using JOLT.
Could someone please help give me a solution for this:

My JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "person_id": "1",
    "resources": ["asd", "zxc"]
  },
  {
    "person_id": "2",
    "resources": ["ghj", "asd"]
  }
]
```

And my expected JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "person_id": "1",
    "resource": "asd"
  },
  {
    "person_id": "1",
    "resource": "zxc"
  },
  {
    "person_id": "2",
    "resource": "ghj"
  },
  {
    "person_id": "2",
    "resource": "asd"
  }
]
```

I had tried this Jolt Specification

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "resources": {
          "*": {
            "@(2,person_id)": "[&].person_id",
            "@": "[&].resource"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But no luck it always maps all values at the same index to 1 array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two consecutive **shift** transformation specs by walking through  the **`resources`** array within the first one such that

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*s": { // this tecnique stands for extracting by the replacement of the asterisk through use of &(2,1) below
          "*": {
            "@(2,person_id)": "[&3].&1.person_id", // to separate by indexes of the array to generate three level for three independent objects
            "@": "[&3].&1.&(2,1)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Great! thank you a lot, exactly what I need. BTW, do you know any useful document to learn those syntax, I messed up with it several days

Comment: You're welcome. There are some links those I like [1](https://erbalvindersingh.medium.com/applying-jolttransform-on-json-object-array-and-fetching-specific-fields-48946870b4fc), [2](https://intercom.help/godigibee/en/articles/3096940-simple-if-else-with-jolt), [3](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/releases), [4](https://cool-cheng.blogspot.com/2019/12/json-jolt-tutorial.html). Have a nice day @ĐìnhTuyên !

Answer (score 1):

You can use this jolt spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*s": {
          "*": {
            "@(2,person_id)": "@(1).person_id",
            "@": "@(1).&(2,1)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```